# SPI clock selection

Tags: spi, clock, clock-speed

Using STM32l476 controller. Master is running at 30 MHz and slave is running 15 MHz.

- In SPImaster, clock should be system clock/2.
- In slave, clock should be system clock/4.

*Question:*

- My understanding is slave need clock from master. Data shifting completely depends on masters clock.
  In that case why datasheet mentions slave clock selection condition?
- Which is max clock speed I can choose in the above scenario?
- What if Master clock is 32 MHz ?How to choose frequency? If you divide 15/4 = 3.75 MHz, with 30 MHz Master clock can be scaled down to 30/8 = 3.75 MHz

Thanks

Comment: Maximum clock frequency is determined by wire length and EMC concerns and not so much by MCU clock capacity.

Answer (score 1):

> In SPImaster clock should be system clock/2 slave clock should be
>   system clock/4

I didn't read the datasheet, but I'm pretty sure it says something like "... should **NOT EXCEED** system clock/..."

> Question 2: Which is max clock speed I can choose in the above
>   scenario?

With the requirement you mentioned, you would end up at max. 15/4 = 3.75 MHz.
But be aware that the max. clock speed also depends on your HW design (wire length, wire type, ...) and your environment (immunity to EMC, ...).